# jquery touchstart not working on document

Tags: jquery, ipad, touchstart

a simple touchstart event will work, if you use this syntax:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwdu4hb9/

```
$(function(){
    $('.test').on('touchstart', function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

But if you want to add your event for all coming elements with `$(document).on(..)` like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwdu4hb9/1/

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('touchstart', '.test', function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

The event will not get triggered.
What is wrong with this call?

Tested on iPad with iOS 8.0.2

Comment: Nothing wrong with code, where do you test it ?

Comment: iPad 3 with iOS 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, is there any reason you are avoiding using `click` event instead of `touchstart`? Generally mobile browsers will handle `click` as a 'touch' event. I've had trouble in the past with touches vs. clicks on different devices (solved w/ modernizr)

At the very least, I would bind both events (`click` and `touchstart`), which would handle both mobile and desktop (updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/srdkgL7o/)

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('touchstart click', '.test', function(e){
         e.stopPropagation(); //stops 'ghost clicks' (double clicking)
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```